# Ionic - A black screen is just flashing / flickering for a while after login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am just a beginner to Ionic.

When I try to login to the application from my login page to the dashboard page, I see a page flickering  or a black flash page appearing for a fraction of second. Any one experienced this before and can let me know how to fix this?

Not sure which part of code produces that, hence unaware of the right code to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed. Seems to be that we shouldn’t conditionally set the rootPage asynchronously. The rootPage is set right away, but if some asynchronous operation is performed first (like checking if a user is authenticated) before determining the rootPage, it’s going to cause issues.

I handle this by setting the root page to the login page, and then on the login page trigger the authentication check within ionViewDidLoad and once it completes, use setRoot to change the page (if necessary).